# ReactJS code compiled successfully , but not printing on Browser

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

After a lot of efforts i was able to install and configure ReactJS. After executing "npm start" command, the code was "COMPILED SUCCESSFULLY" and redirected me to the web browser.
But **there wasn't any output**, ie., the browser was "**blank**".
Can anyone resolve this?? ( my first post here )

Also check the code that i have used..

**index.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id = "app"></div>
      <script src = 'index_bundle.js'></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
        <h1> Hello World</h1>
        <p>Hello </p>   
        </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.js';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**package.json snippet**

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
   entry: './main.js',
   output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '/bundle'),
      filename: 'index_bundle.js'
   },
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8001
   },
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   plugins:[
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
         template: './index.html'
      })
   ]
}
```

The only issue is the output is **not getting displayed** on browser..

**command prompt**
[COMMAND PROMPT AFTER "npm start"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFaZ0.png)

**browser**
[output not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUss4.png)

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console?

Answer (score 2):

Add an `.babelrc` file in root folder with following:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

And `package.json` is expected to include following dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  }
```

### Update

Also update `webpack.config.js` to:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./main.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/bundle"),
    filename: "index_bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 8001
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: ,babelrc already exists... the code and everything is correct , but not getting why its not executing

Comment: Can you share your code to check coz exact above code did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path and change `Component` to `component`.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact  />
        </div>
      </Router> 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In component, when using the useState hook to manage the text state. Sometimes, an **initial value for the state variable** can be missing. When useState is called without an initial value, the state variable (text in this case) will be undefined initially.
Eg:

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");
```